# How to make alerting window come to the foreground

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

When a particular window is flashing orange on the taskbar in Windows 10, I would like it to come to the foreground.

[image]

How can I configure Windows to allow this?

Comment: This is typically entirely controlled by the application itself.

Comment: Programs can choose to flash their windows, that part is app specific. Windows has a set of rules as to when a program can take focus. If a program attempts to make itself the foreground window, and it doesn't comply with a rule, Windows flashes the taskbar button instead changing foreground window. See **Remarks** section https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, maybe this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-opening-pop-up-window-in-background/1f0d266f-aefe-4754-934f-d349df98fcbd) is what you are looking for.  You can accomplish what you are looking for by setting the **ForegroundLockTimeout** value within the registry.  The instructions are as follows:

> Before proceeding, make sure to create a System Restore point on the computer.
>
> 1. Press **Windows + R** key to open Run window.
> 2. Type **regedit** and press Enter.
> 3. Browse to the key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop**
> 4. On the right hand side locate and double click on the key **ForegroundLockTimeout**
> 5. Select the button Decimal and then then type **0** (zero) in the value data box.
> 6. Click on OK.
> 7. Restart the computer and check if issue persists.

Source: [Windows 10 opening pop-up window in background behind main window, failed to focus on pop-up](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-opening-pop-up-window-in-background/1f0d266f-aefe-4754-934f-d349df98fcbd?auth=1)

Comment: @TarlisonBrito - Please take note of the formatting improvements I did for your answer.

Comment: Oops, thanks! I'm new here :)